# Changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH for pyrit install

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm trying to build pyrit without root access. I installed libpcap to a /tmp/sunjay/somefolder

I changed the setup.py using -I so it could find pcap.h

Now I am running into this problem:
http://pastebin.com/47f01XcF

As you can see, it is looking for lpcap in /usr/bin, which is wrong.
I tried 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/tmp/sunjay/lib' from the command line but it makes no difference. How can I tell the script to look in a different directory for lpcap?

I have been unable to find the .py file where path is set or able to change the following line:
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu_sse2.o -lcrypto -lpcap -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.so

In your answer, please be specific. I have been working on this problem for several hours with no success. Keep in mind, I have only user privileges. Thanks.

Comment: Run "/sbin/ldconfig" after you export.

Comment: /sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied

Comment: FYI it it not looking for lpcap in /usr/bin -> The linker (`ld`) is located in /usr/bin

Comment: still working on a solution to this problem with no luck.

Comment: These two lines in the extensions block of setup.py fixed the problem. 
include_dirs=["../libpcap-1.3.0"],
library_dirs=["../libpcap-1.3.0"],